# Can I connect two "Networks" to the same port using sockets in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, network-programming, pickle

I am working on an online multiplayer game to play with my friends. Can I use the following Network module (created by following a tutorial on YouTube) twice? By "twice" I mean... Can I create two similar network modules with different specific tasks and then use them on the same port? If so, do I need to shut the first one down before using the second one?

Here's how the modules look like, more or less:

```
import socket
import pickle

#Network

class Network():

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.connection = self.connect()
        self.p = self.get_player()  

    #Returns Player Objects
    def getP(self):
        return self.p

    

    def get_player(self):
        return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))


    #Connects the client to the server
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)          #Simply establishes the connection
                                        

        except:
            print("Unable to connect")
    

    #Sends the data from the client to the server and returns the other clients' data to the caller client
    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)

    def sendOnly(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

Just tell me if you need more info. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you include a few lines to show what you tried to do and why it doesn't work?

Comment: What would be the point? If you had two processes listening to the same port on the same interface then which process should receive a connection request on that port?

Comment: @DanR I just now tried using the same Network class twice (two different instances). Seems to work pretty fine.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I needed them to do different tasks and couldn't figure out how to make it work with just one Network instance, but I managed to find out a way using two instances. What caused me the "headache" was the __init__ part, which when called creates the attributes. I had an attribute which consisted in a method of the same class that looped until it received data from the server. The server only sent data one time for one instance, but not for the other one. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: @LucasGran so if it's working, is your question basically, "what could go wrong with this"? In that case, it looks like you have to client (outgoing) connections, so yes it's fine to have two simultaneous outgoing connections to the same server; they will have different local port numbers for the client side of the connection.

Comment: @Dan R At the time I posted the question I had some problems making it work for me, but that's a long story. So... Yes, I guess that's my question. Thanks for the info!